# How to define field of rational numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In Abstract Algebra text by Pinter on page number 2 following is mentioned.

> The field of rational numbers, ie, of quotients p/q where p and q
>   $\neq 0$ are the ordinary integers subject to the ordinary operations
>   of arithmetic.

If p and q both are not equal to zero then zero is not in the field and consequently it is not a field, if it is not a typo then how do I read the statement?

Comment: ...where $p$ (*potentially zero*) and nonzero $q$ are the ordinary integers subject to the ordinary operations of arithmetic.

Comment: "$\neq 0$" apples only to $q$.

Comment: The field of rational numbers, ie, of quotients p/q with p in Z  and q in Z with q=/=0 are the ordinary integers subject to the ordinary operations of arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean $p$ and ($q \neq 0$) are the ordinary integers ...  $p$ is allowed to be $0$, but $q$ is not.  It is a common ambiguity in English whether the description non-zero should apply to $p$ as well as $q$ in a sentence like this.  Here it should not.

Comment: Actually, in natural English, the ambiguity would not occur: "where $p$ and $q\ne0$" would be written "where $p$ and non-zero $q$". Bu I also do not see the original formulation ambiguous, whereas with "where $p,q\ne0$" (which many prefer to the strangely arranged "where $p\ne0\ne q$" when they *really* want both to be non-zero) I *might* wish the author to be more precise